# sql: select distinct couple(distinct relation) from two column of same data type

Tags: sql, set, distinct, relation

I have two column of the same type in a table:

```
col1    | col2
--------+---------
AAA     |    BBB
BBB     |    AAA
CCC     |    DDD
DDD     |    CCC
EEE     |    FFF
```

I want to write a request for a result like his:

```
col1    | col2
--------+---------
AAA     |    BBB
CCC     |    DDD
EEE     |    FFF
```

I tried all I know, but no good result

Help please!

Comment: Not sure, but try self join on col1 of 1 = col2 of 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

This works given your sample data. You might need to account for NULLs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END,
    CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
FROM
    My_Table
```